# Text from file to float

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

I have `std::vector<std::string> WorldData`. It contains every line of my file called world.txt (there are opengl 3d coordinations) it looks like:

```
-3.0 0.0 -3.0 0.0 6.0
-3.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0
3.0 0.0 3.0 6.0 0.0 etc.
```

How could i transform these strings to float variables?
When I tried:

```
scanf(WorldData[i].c_str(), "%f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &tX, &tY);
or
scanf(WorldData[i].c_str(), "%f %f %f %f %f\n", &x, &y, &z, &tX, &tY);
```

variables x, y, z, tX, tY get some weird numbers.

Comment: Did you really use scanf?  You should be using sscanf if you're reading from a string.

Comment: omg i haven't seen that, i guess it's time to sleep :P thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

Rather than read from a file into a vector, then from the vector into coordinates, I'd read a coordinate directly from the file:

```
struct coord { 
    double x, y, z, tX, tY;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, coord &c) { 
    return is >> c.x >> c.y >> c.z >> c.tX >> c.tY;
}
```

Then you can create a vector of coordinates using an `istream_iterator`:

```
std::ifstream in("world.txt");

// initialize vector of coords from file:
std::vector<coord> coords((std::istream_iterator<coord>(in)),
                           std::istream_iterator<coord>());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [sstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/):

```
std::istringstream iss(WorldData[i]);
iss >> x >> y >> z >> tX >> tY;
```

Comment: That should be `std::istringstream iss; iss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(WorldData[i].c_str(), WorldData[i].size());` if you want to avoid an unnecessary duplication of the data inside `WorldData[i]`.